# WINE wont open MinecraftInstaller.exe

Tags: command-line, wine

I am new to Linux and I am using Ubuntu right now. I downloaded wine and I don't remember from what website, but I downloaded MinecraftInstaller.exe. When I tried to open it using the command `wine MinecraftInstaller.exe` I got this error:

```
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
  at MinecraftInstaller.App.Main () [0x0007d] in <e58509810b7a49feb659918dfe08015a>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is in your output: `fixme` and `FileNotFound`.

Your software looks for Windows features that simply do not exist in Wine.

Your software cannot be run using Wine.